# Sign Out as HTTP GET?

Tags: rest, http, post, get, put

I often see *Sign Out* functionality implemented as a `GET` HTTP request.  Is this good practice?

Once you are signed out, the *Sign Out* method is idempotent, but it isn't when you're signed in.

When you're signed in, it is changing state, so should it be a `POST` or PUT`?

Does impotency allow the first request to set `the state of the application`?

Comment: Check this answer: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196871#answer-196873

Comment: (`DELETE` verb could also be a good candidate for logout)